# Is there a way to assign a task to more than one user?

Tags: 2010, development, task-list

I am creating a tool that needs to assign a single task to one ore more users. The task list may not be in the same site collection so I cannot simply add a SPGroup or use AD Groups due to our farm set up.

Will I have to create my own custom list with a custom workflow? Or is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "the task list may not be in the same site collection"? What does the tool do? Why should the task list for the tool be in more than one site collections? If you assign a task to a user, then the user gets the task assigned. How can it NOT be in the same site collection? Please explain why the regular task assignment does not work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow multiple selection on the Assigned to column in the list, this way you will be able to assign individual users.

Comment: Did you understand that the task list may not be in the same site collection?

Comment: OK then, it would better to explain further the whole situation? is the tool mentioned at the beginning of the question the same as the list and workflow mentioned at the end? What's this tool? Is it a webpart? list definition?

Comment: I created a 'Custom List' with an event receiver based on ListUrl attribute. Then put a multi-value people picker for a field and use the event receiver to send emails about the user(s) 'Task'